# How do I create/login to a Spotify developer account?

Tags: spotify

The developer login rejects my Facebook credentials that I'm using for my normal Spotify account. How can I login? Do I need to create a separate developer account? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to login true this url [Spotify Developer login](https://developer.spotify.com/login/). When logged in you can enable your Spotify account for the Spotify Apps Development part, see this link: [Spotify apps](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/#developer-account).

Hope this helped!

Comment: Are you using using your Facebook credentials? When I try to login using my Facebook credentials, the system returns "Invalid username/password combination". However, I'm currently logged in on the main Spotify site. I don't get it... do I need a separate developer account?

Comment: I checked it again for you. When I log in at [link](http://www.spotify.com/) with Facebook, I'm only logged in on the 'Spotify' website. To be logged in on this page: [link](https://developer.spotify.com/), you need to login with your developers account (and not your Facebook account).

In other words, (as far as I know) you really need to have a developer account to start develop!

Comment: Thanks so much for checking. How did you create your developer account? I don't see a link or any instructions for creating a new account.

Comment: I came by this on Github: "Sign up for a [developer account on Spotify](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/#developer-account). It takes about 24 hours to get access, so email mager@spotify.com with your Spotify username for rush access."

Answer (score 0):

Set up your device number and password here

http://www.spotify.com/us/help/faq/devices/connect-devices/

and use those credentials to log in the developer site.